# Should I use "onmousedown" event, if I want to target desktop and mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsiveness

I´d like to know. If I want to make a responsive website, should I use the "onmousedown" event? Would it be triggered on all devices?
I have tested the simulation of Firefox, on mobile I get the "onmousedown" event.

Is there such an event? That would be triggered on mouse down and/or on touch , in desktop and mobile devices?

Thanks.

Comment: [How to learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)

Comment: @adeneo, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Guarantee for all devices is nearly impossible due to the versions, nonstandard browsers, embedded browsers etc. You should first think about what your target platforms and what are the minimum browser versions. Then, you should follow the web standards and use common functions. Yes "onmousedown" is a standard event supported by majority of modern browsers, however it has also exceptions such as

> The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

stated in the [onmousedown documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp).

Comment: I'm searching for an event that is triggered both on mobile and desktop devices. Could I use "onmousedown" for that? I need to target just the actual browsers

Comment: Yes, you can. However; you should test it in on many devices or simulators as you can to be sure. I had many weird situations similar to your problem so it is the only way to set the minimum versions and platforms which will be used.

Comment: I see. Thanks @ali

Comment: Look what I found. https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/

"The jQuery Mobile vmousedown event handler simulates the "onmousedown" event handler on mobile devices."